# Regex to match string

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I have array of strings with following data:

```
'STSO/82465'
'CPB'
550
'B'
'IEC2'
'IEC2'
50
525
680
1550,1175
'500000/V3'
'23585/V3'
''
etc...
```

Positions marked with '' are strings rest is double, I need help with regex to get only strings.

Comment: Why a regex? Go through each line and keep the ones containing `'`?

Comment: @Chris: i guess OP has marked them just for us.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Guess that could be the case. Let's hope there's no strings that happen to be all digits then..!

Comment: Small correction i get the data from text file values that are strings are marked by ' ' so in array it looks like that "'IEC2'" etc.

Comment: What are the rules to select one but not the other string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need regex for this?

```
double d;
string[] noDoubles = Array.FindAll(arr, s => !double.TryParse(s, out d));
```

this accepts the decimal separator of the current culture. You can change it if you use the overload of `double.TryParse`. It seems to be `,` for you as your sample data suggests.

If you want to allow point as decimal separator:

```
Array.FindAll(arr, s => !double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out d));
```

If the non-doubles really start all with `'` you could also make it simpler:

```
string[] noDoubles = Array.FindAll(arr, s => s.StartsWith("'"));
```

Comment: Is there a similar method to get only doubles?

Comment: @user3290117: yes, either the `double.Parse` approach(note the missing `!`): `Array.FindAll(arr, s => double.TryParse(s, out d));` or `Array.FindAll(arr, s => !s.StartsWith("'"))`

Answer (score 1):

the `String` 's `StartsWith` `EndsWith` methods should do the trick:

```
var tab = new[]
        {
            "'STSO/82465'",
            "'CPB'",
            "550",
            "'B'",
            "'IEC2'",
            "'IEC2'",
            "50",
            "525",
            "680",
            "1550,1175",
            "'500000/V3'",
            "'23585/V3'"
        };
        foreach (var s in tab)
        {
            if (s.StartsWith("'") && s.EndsWith("'"))
            {
                //use the s
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ one-liner:

```
var linesWithStrings = allLines.Where( l => l.StartsWith( "'" ) );
```

Or, if you want to strip the quotes:

```
var linesWithStrings = from s in allLines
                       where s.Length >= 2 && s.StartsWith( "'" ) && s.EndsWith( "'" )
                       select s.Substring( 1, s.Length - 2 );
```